# Laravel 5.1 add a blank value to Form::select() with $model->lists()

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form that has a select input that called `customer_id`. This field is not required, and I fetch the options via the `Customer` Model. My code looks like this:

```
{!! Form::select('customer', $customers->lists('email', 'id'), null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

so far so good, right? but the thing is that when I don't want to choose a customer, I can't choose a blank option. Is there a way to add a blank option so I wouldn't need to pick a customer all the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[''=>'---']+$customers->lists('email', 'id')->toArray()
```

or

```
array_merge([''=>'---'], $customers->lists('email', 'id')->toArray())
```